# SQL Vertica on Tableau: row_number over partition by multiple fields error

Tags: sql, tableau-api, window-functions, vertica, row-number

I have a query that uses

```
row_number() over(partition by a,b)
```

When I run the query in dbvisualizer, it runs fine. When I try to use it as a custom SQL query in Tableau, it throws the error:

```
Error 3537: Incorrect number of parameters for prepared statement _PLAN000011EBDD67590_42
```

Any idea what I should do? I need my data partitioned by both `a` and `b` but Tableau just isn't happy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very probably not the ROW_NUMBER() function that perplexes Tableau.
"Incorrect number of parameters" usually means that you have a different number of parameter markers in a query that contains for example `WHERE purchase_date = ?`, and you maybe try to pass two values in a filter of your report.

I would check for the query that Tableau wants to send in detail, and look at the filter you are using to find inconsistencies .

Comment: You're right, the problem was caused by a line I had commented out with `--`...I guess maybe I can't use comments in custom_sql in Tableau?